# Is there a way to hide the cycles shader node when using my own render plugin?

Tags: add-on

I'm working on my own renderer plugin for Blender 2.8.
I have my own set of shader nodes.

Is there a way to hide the cycles shader node when my renderer is selected as the rendering engine in Blender?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

cycles is an addon that can be disabled in the user preferences.

Comment: Even if cycles is disabled, those nodes are still visible since EEVEE and cycles share the same set of nodes, I am just speculating.

It would be nice if those internal nodes' poll method can be overridden so that I can hide them any way I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom node tree type for your nodes (i.e. they are completely separate from Cycles/Eevee nodes), then you can hide the Cycles shader node tree by setting the class attribute `bl_use_shading_nodes_custom` in your implementation of the `RenderEngine` class to `True`:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html#bpy.types.RenderEngine.bl_use_shading_nodes_custom

On the other hand, if you put your custom nodes in the Cycles/Eevee node tree, I do not know of a way to hide the other nodes (I suspect it's not possible).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried your attribute. However, it is not exactly what I want.

Basically, this flag only removes the node options from the right-click menu. It doesn't hide the existed nodes that have already been created before. Eventually, there is still the possibility to connect cycles node to custom ones.

Do you know if there is any example does a perfect job of extending the system?
As far as I know, most of the blender render plugin, like mitsuba, pbrt, readeon pro render, renderman, don't handle it perfectly.

Comment: You might want to clarify in your question that you put your custom nodes into the Cycles shader node tree instead of using a custom node tree type (which I assumed).

Comment: What I would like is to create some custom shading nodes into the cycles shader node tree. However, I don't want to cross-connect to the cycles nodes and my custom ones, which is why I would like to hide the native cycle/eevee nodes when my rendering engine is picked.
So do you have the solution to the problem?